# Is there a way to get all suggestion in external module in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

VS Code does not show all the methods of the current object.

Current behavior:
[image: s]

What I expect:

After executing this code, I see all the methods of the object. I want to see all of them in a pop-up suggestion box.

```
const officegen = require("officegen");
var docx = officegen("docx");
console.log(docx);
```

Result:

```
officegen {
  ... // skipped a lot of output
  setTheme: [Function],
  setDocTitle: [Function],
  setDocSubject: [Function],
  setDocKeywords: [Function],
  setDescription: [Function],
  setDocCategory: [Function],
  setDocStatus: [Function],
  data: [],
  createP: [Function],
  createListOfDots: [Function],
  createListOfNumbers: [Function],
  putPageBreak: [Function],
  addPageBreak: [Function],
  createTable: [Function],
  createJson: [Function],
  createByJson: [Function],
  getHeader: [Function],
  getFooter: [Function] }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VSCode use typescript engine to statically analyse js codebase, then give you the suggestion. However, due to the flexibility of js, it's not possible to do perfect statical analysis without some help from code author.

In your case, the "officegen" lib's source code probably isn't optimal to allow typescript to analyse and provide best suggestion. There's no configuration you can do improve it.

You can however write a `.d.ts` file to help typescript understand content of "officegen" lib. But that job requires a lot of effort.